# What is wrong with my display?

Tags: windows, display, hardware-failure, colors

My laptop display looks like this:
[image: bad display]
[solid color image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KRKG7.jpg)

As you can see, there are horizontal patches of distorted colours. I have a hunch that it is a software issue, but I am unsure. I have been using an external display for a long time, so I didn't pay much attention to this and don't remember how and when this distortion started. I vaguely remember that it might have started when I was setting up my external monitor, and that's why I didn't think of it much at the time.
I tried running the laptop without the external display connected, but it still looks like this. I have Windows 10 with Ubuntu in dual boot configuration, and the display looks the same in both.
There is no other issue with the display, as far as I can tell.
It has been so long, so I am unsure about the external display hypothesis.
How can I find out the issue, and how can I troubleshoot it?

It's difficult to take images that show the issue clearly. It does not show up with white/black background. It shows up more with some colours than others.

The display looks weirdly pixelated. Look at this comparison:
[laptop image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hSanD.jpg)
[external monitor image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RE3j0.jpg)

Comment: Because of the complex background image, the problem is not very visible. Use a solid color if possible. Also make sure to position the camera in the center of the screen to reduce moiré a little. // If you want to rule out software, just open the firmware setup and check there.

Comment: @DanielB what do you mean by firmware setup? Please elaborate.

Comment: What is colloquially known as “BIOS setup”.

Comment: How old is the display?

Comment: @Ramhound It's 1.5 year old Lenovo laptop

Comment: You have owned this laptop for 1.5 years, but is the laptop new, or did you purchased it used from somebody?

Comment: @Ramhound I purchased it new. It's still in warranty.

Comment: It looks like a hardware issue, specifically, the display.  The fact the display looks the same in multiple operating systems indicates the problem is not caused by a driver or specifically a lack of a working driver

Comment: If it's still in warranty, don't think twice - get the screen replaced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was my question.

I contacted Lenovo. They sent out a tech who replaced my display. He told me it was a display issue. There was no damage. As it was in warranty, everything was done free of cost.

So, if anyone else has the same issue, contact support.